# Error validating settings: only one positional argument is allowed

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

The problem: I need to import a csv file to a mongodb, but i need to specify the field types and still use the --headline cause in my csv the first line is where the fieldnames are.

Here is what i'm tryin:

`mongoimport --type csv -d solution2 -c data --headerline --drop dados.csv direction.int32\(\),latitude.double\(\),longitude.double\(\),metrictimestamp.date\(\),odometer.int32\(\),routecode.int32\(\),speed.int32\(\),device_deviceid.int32\(\),vehicle_vehicleid.int32\(\) --columnsHaveTypes`

"solution2" is the DB name, "data" is the collection and "dados.csv" is my archive.

I'm getting this error message: Error validating settings: only one positional argument is allowed.

Comment: What is the operating system and also please post a sample record from the CSV file.

Comment: I'm on windows 10. I can't post a sample cause my csv has 19 million lines and is restricted data

Comment: You are missing the `--fields` before the first field name.  You need to choose to use one of `--fields` or `--headline`.  With `--columnsHaveTypes` you should be able to edit the first line of the file to add the types there, or delete the first line from the .csv and pass the field names on the command line.

Comment: So... I can't use both --headline and --fields? I can't change the csv file, how could i skip the first line on the import?